# A listener service always Listening to a particular hotword in iOS

Tags: ios, listener, dialogflow-es

newbie here. I have a client who has a private appstore. The requirement is a dialogflow based chat assistant that can help with an application already deployed in their private app store. They want the assistant to listen to a particular keyword and start a dialogflow interaction where they would ask the query. I know for a fact that iOS doesn't allow a service to run after a minute. Since this is related to only one application that too deployed from a particular appstore is there a way I can accomplish this?

I have considered the following alternative as well, 
- Controlling the application through SIRI, but the client wants to know if a custom 'hotword' listener or invocation word is possible.

Thank You

Comment: You would need to write an app that continually samples audio with the microphone and analyses it looking for your keyword, but even then you won't be able to launch your app to the foreground; you would need to post a notification advising the user to tap it to open the app. This also won't be very battery friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, so I'll give you a broad answer.

1. You want to keep the microphone on and listen for a keyword. Use `AudioComponentInstance` to keep the mic on. If you set it up right, you'll have a `recordingCallback` that gives you the latest mic input. You can keep track of the user's speech in the callback with `NSMutableData` and every X milliseconds, check if they said the keyword.
2. One way you can check for the keyword: send everything the user says to DialogFlow. You can setup a DialogFlow gRPC connection in your app (Google Cloud has iOS samples that you can copy). With a connection configured, stream all the audio data from your `recordingCallback` to DialogFlow and check if the user says the keyword. **Problem with this method:** DialogFlow has a 1 minute streaming limit and it's also a super energy intensive way to do what you want.
3. So second option for checking the keyword: train your own mini neural network using TensorFlow to recognize the exact keyword you want (if it's a common keyword, training data will be available somewhere and there are plenty of Tensorflow audio recognition tutorials online). "Hey Siri" works in this way (a lot more complicated but essentially this). Fair warning, converting TF models into TF Lite models for iOS apps is tricky when audio is involved because ops like `DecodeWav` aren't supported by Tensorflow Lite. You could also try converting your trained TF model into a Core ML model with the `tf-coreml` tool published by the Tensorflow team.
4. Once your keyword mechanism detects the keyword, you use a DialogFlow gRPC connection to stream audio data from your `recordingCallback` to DialogFlow and you wait for a `DFQueryResult` with the intent information. You can use that intent information to do whatever you need to do in your private app store.
5. You mentioned Siri. I have no idea how you would connect Siri to a private app store in your own app. You need to provide more details, but check out the Siri docs on shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to invoke chat using Siri in iOS. Probably you may want to see [Siri Kit](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/) for that. But if you want to communicate with Dialogflow from iOS app you can do that by using [Dialogflow iOS client](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-apple-client).